# Convert Binary Tree in Zigzag order to a Doubly linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, binary-tree

Ii have a problem. i have to convert a Binary Tree in its zigZag format to a doubly linked list.

```
 Given BT:
                 [1]
          [2]                  [3]
      [4]      [5]         [6]        [7]
    [8]  [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15]
```

ZigZag order of BT in DLL:
      [1] [3] [2] [4] [5] [6] [7] [15] [14] [13] [12] [11] [10] [9] [8]

Here is my pseudocode:

```
DLLNode* ConvertBTToZigZgDLL(Node* root)
{
  DLLNode* start=createDLLNode(root->data);
  DLLNode* tail=start;
  Stack<Node> stack1, stack2;
  stack1.push(root->left);
  stack1.push(root->right);
  while( !stack1.Empty() || !stack2.Empty() )
  {
     while(stack1.HasElement())
     {
       Node* temp=stack1.Pop();
       stack2.push(temp->right);
       stack2.push(temp->left);
       tail=Attach(tail,createDLLNode(temp->data));
       tail=tail->next;
     }
     while(stack2.HasElement())
     {
       Node* temp=stack2.Pop();
       stack1.push(temp->left);
       stack1.push(temp->right);
       tail=Attach(tail,createDLLNode(temp->data));
       tail=tail->next;
     }
  }
  return start;
```

}
  Here TimeComplexity O(N), where N is the no of nodes in the given Binary Tree.

```
  DLLNode* Attach(DLLNode* source, DLLNode* dest)
  {
     source.Next=dest;
     dest.prev=source;
     return source;
  }

  DLLNode* CreateDLLNode(int data)
  {
    DLLNode* res=malloc(sizeof(struct DLLNode));
    res->data=data;
    res->prev=NULL;
    res->next=NULL;
    return res;
   }
```

All i want to know **what is wrong in the logic** of my code.

One of friend is saying the above code wont work and its wrong. i couldn't able to find any usecase where my logic will fail (Exclude null check/null/empty nodes)

Just check the logic of my code and let me know.

My Logic is simple: use 2 stacks. In stack1 i always pushes the Left child first and then the right child and in stack2 i always pushes the right child first and left child second. initially loads stack1 while stack1 is non empty pop and pushes the corresponding right/left child nodes in stack2. For the above example my stack states should be like s1-B[2,3]T s2-B[7,6,5,4]T s1-B[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]T  B-stack bottom T-Stack top. Pls check again. thanks.

Comment: My code is not checking any levels of any nodes as given in the other post. and my concern is whether the above logic of my code is correct or not.. this same code is nowhere else.. Pls understand and help me.. Thanks..

Comment: When trying to ask about an algorithm, it is easier for others to criticize if you state in plain words what you try to do (as compared with a particular implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm:

Use a modified BFS algorithm where instead of a single fifo queue two stacks are used `stack1` is used to contain the nodes in the levels that are to be visited right-to-left, while  `stack2` contains the nodes that are to be visited left-to-right.

The list is initialized with the root node, and the first level (closest to root) is stored in `stack1`. So the first pass through `stack1` will pull the first level in the appropriate order.

For the general case proof, assuming that the elements in `stack1` are stored in the right order, pulling the nodes from `stack1` for level N ensures that they are processed in right-to-left order. For each so processed node, the subtrees are stored in `stack2` in first right, then left. This guarantees that the list of nodes as *retrieved* from `stack2` for level N+1 has left-to-right order. The `while` loop completes when there are no more nodes at level N. At this point extracting the nodes from `stack2` will retrieve all the nodes from level N+1 in left-to-right order.

Conversely, when pulling nodes from `stack2` in each left-to-right level, stores the child nodes in `stack1` first left, then right, ensuring that when they are pulled out in the next iteration in right-to-left order.

So basically the algorithm is proven to be sound. Now that does not ensure that the implementation is. In particular you are adding all NULL pointers to the stacks and that means that you will retrieve them, and then try to read through them.

Comment: all i want is my logic works or not. i gave this solution in an interview/written test last saturday.. that interviewer said it never works.. even i asked the HR to re-evaluate my answer, the same guy again said it wont work.. he didn't even spend more than 30 seconds on my answer.. Thanks again.. Thank you so much.. i got back my confidence.. Thanks.. You guys help other developers keep their spirit up.. Thanks.. this developer community need u guys.. Thanks! i am sorry i couldn't able to add any points to ur reputation as it says i need min. 15 reputations..

Comment: @javasoul: When you write code, and you know what you are doing, you should be able to provide a proof similar to this in a few seconds. The one thing I learned from the algorithms course (I had studied algorithms myself before that) was that proofs are a good thing, as they demonstrate an algorithm or point into where the solution is wrong. When the interviewer told you that it was wrong, you should have stepped up and ask for the reason, explain your reasoning. That is usually more important than the algorithm itself in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

This is already covered in another question.

See [this stackoverview set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742772/how-to-convert-a-binary-search-tree-into-a-doubly-linked-list).

Comment: No my concern is about the logic in my solution.. whether the logic in mine is correct or not.. that only i want to know..

Comment: You are probably quite new in SO, in general, when you only want to indicate that the question has already been answered, you should add a comment to the question, rather than an answer with only a link. Once you get sufficient reputation, you will be able to *vote to close as duplicate*, but in the meantime, it is accustomed to just add a comment.

Comment: In the other post the replies are not giving standard pseudo code / given code is printing the data in the tree in zigzag -not returning any Dynamic Linked List. Also that is an old - last year post.

Comment: @javasoul: A couple of things, first is that if the question is the same, the fact that it is new or old is irrelevant: it is the same question and has answers that deal with it. Conversion from code that prints to code that inserts in a list is trivial. Finally, as you have asked what is wrong with your implementation, you will find that some of the answers there do point to the requirement that you are not fulfilling: the order of the elements in the same levels in your algorithm is always the same, while the requirements state that each level should process the nodes in reverse order.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the reply. >>"the order of the elements.." - i didn't get it. Its ZigZag means if i end at left node at a level then next level should start at left node and if i end at right node then next level should start at right. i have corrected my code -the push method swapped for the stacks. Pls check again. Thanks.

Comment: @javasoul: I believed that the logic was incorrect, but after some more thinking it might be correct.

Comment: @David: Thanks for checking it.